# Selenium: Download in firefox driver not starting

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm trying to do the download a file from a third party website, so I'm unable to access the code on the other side. I'm using firefox webdriver in headless mode. I'm unable to test this with Chrome, because my server doesn't have a display and Chrome gives me an error when trying to run it in headless mode. I'm also unable to make the browser logging for Firefox work (I've tried this in the profile section of the code, but no logs appear) so I'm unable to get debugging information out from selenium making things incredibly difficult. I would truly appreciate if someone could give me hints into how to make downloads like this work with firefox. Would it be possible to somehow get the script output that is responsible for creating the file and initiating the download through selenium driver? I believe I could make the download start if I just got the URL that the script creates.

The test looks like this:

Get the driver and connect to the url -> Login -> Get redirected to the page -> Open correct menu -> Open correct sub-menu -> Open correct tab -> Insert start date

This part works without problems, but:

-> Click "Excel" button -> Download starts

Refuses to work no matter what I do. I used screenshots from the driver to confirm that the process starts and finishes, but when the download is supposed to start nothing happens.

This picture shows that the process has started and the button has been clicked:

[image: First]

picture shows that the process has entered the next stage
[image: Second]

After this the browser should immediately do a GET query (Most likely triggered by javascript, this I can't verify) and fetch the right file. When doing this manually, the download starts without a separate popup window on normal browser so it shouldn't ask it for selenium either.

I'll paste the code responsible for the query. This is the file that creates the driver and gets the profile and options:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');
const chromium = require('chromium');
const FirefoxProfile = require("firefox-profile");
const {Builder, Browser, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
require('chromedriver');
require('geckodriver');

async function loginWithForm(driver, url, formOpts, formData){
  await driver.get(url)
  await driver.findElement(By.name(formOpts.username)).sendKeys(formData.username);
  await driver.findElement(By.name(formOpts.password)).sendKeys(formData.password);
  if(!formOpts.submit){
    var result = await driver.findElement(By.className('btn-primary')).click();
  }else if(formOpts.submit.type == "id"){
    var result = await driver.findElement(By.id(formOpts.submit.value)).click();
  }
  return result;
}

async function clearFieldByXpath(driver, path){
  await driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).clear();
  return;
}

async function clickById(driver, id){
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  let el = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(id), 3000));
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  await el.click()
  return el;
}

async function clickByXpath(driver, path){
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  await driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).click();
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  return;
}

function getOptions(dd){
  let options = new firefox.Options();    
  options.addArguments('--headless')
  options.addArguments('download.default_directory',dd)
  options.setPreference('devtools.console.stdout.content', true)
  options.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
  options.setPreference('browser.download.dir',dd)
  options.setPreference('browser.download.useDownloadDir',true)
  options.setPreference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting',false)
  options.setPreference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', false)
  options.setPreference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk','application/vnd.ms-excel, application/octet-stream') // the response header for the file contains: content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel
'application/pdf,image/jpeg,image/jpg,text/calendar,text/csv')
  return options;
}


function getProfile(){
  let profile = new FirefoxProfile()
  profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.file", "/opt/intr/dev-server/assets/firefox_console") // 777 permissions
  profile.setPreference("webdriver.firefox.logfile", "/opt/intr/dev-server/assets/firefox_browser") // 777 permissions
  profile.setPreference('browser.download.dir','/opt/intr/dev-server/assets/') // 777 permissions
  profile.setPreference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', false)
  profile.setPreference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk','application/vnd.ms-excel, application/octet-stream') // the response header for the file contains: content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel
  return profile;
}


async function getDriver(dd, cb){
  let options = getOptions(dd);
  let profile = getProfile();
  let capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.firefox();
  profile.encoded(async function(err, encodedProfile) {
    capabilities.set("firefox_profile", encodedProfile) // this won't carry on to the driver. When getting .getCapabilities() there is no parameter in the Map with name "firefox_profile"
    const driver = await new Builder()
      .forBrowser('firefox')
      .withCapabilities(capabilities)
      .setFirefoxOptions(options)
      .build();
    cb(driver)
  });
}

async function getElementById(driver, id){
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  let elements = await driver.findElement(By.id(id))
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  return elements;
}

async function getElementByXpath(driver, path){
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  let elements = await driver.findElement(By.xpath(path))
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  return elements;
}

async function setFieldByXpath(driver, path, value){
  await driver.sleep(1000)
  await driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).sendKeys(value)
  return
}

async function waitById(driver, id){
  let present = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(id), 3000));
  return present
}

module.exports = { clickById, clearFieldByXpath, clickByXpath, getDriver, getElementById, getElementByXpath, loginWithForm, setFieldByXpath, waitById}
```

Here is the test itself that is in another file:

```
  async openFeedback(fromDate, to){
    this.driver.manage().window().maximize()
    await webscraper.clickById(this.driver, 'menu__food-dropdown');
    await webscraper.clickById(this.driver, 'menu__feedback-feedback');
    await this.driver.sleep(1000)
    await webscraper.clickById(this.driver, "gwt-uid-14")
    await webscraper.clearFieldByXpath(this.driver, "//div[@class='v-slot v-align-middle'][1]/div/input")
    await webscraper.setFieldByXpath(this.driver, "//div[@class='v-slot v-align-middle'][1]/div/input", '21.4.2023');
    await this.driver.sleep(1000)
    let downloader = await webscraper.getElementByXpath(this.driver, "//div[@class='v-horizontallayout v-layout v-horizontal v-widget jamixbuttons v-horizontallayout-jamixbuttons smallmargin v-horizontallayout-smallmargin wrapping v-horizontallayout-wrapping menustyle v-horizontallayout-menustyle']/div[7]/div")
    await downloader.sendKeys(Key.ENTER)
    await this.driver.sleep(10000)
    this.driver.quit()
    return
  }
```

This initializes the driver:

```
  static async initialize(url, cb){
    webscraper.getDriver('/opt/intr/dev-server/assets/reports', (driver)=>{
      cb(new Jamix(driver, url)); // the directory permissions are for now set to 777
    });
  }
```

This starts the whole test:

```
  await Jamix.Jamix.initialize("https://someurl", async (jamix)=>{
    await jamix.login({"username":"j_username","password":"j_password","submit":{"type":"id","value":"button-login"}},{"username":"xxxxxxx","password":"xxxxxxx"}) // Login works
    await jamix.openFeedback('21.4.2023','21.4.2023'); 
  });
```

This is what my defined capabilities should look like:

```
Capabilities {
  map_: Map(3) {
    'browserName' => 'firefox',
    'moz:debuggerAddress' => true,
    'firefox_profile' => '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'
  }
}
```

This is what i get from .getCapabilities:

```
Capabilities {
  map_: Map(22) {
    'acceptInsecureCerts' => false,
    'browserName' => 'firefox',
    'browserVersion' => '112.0.1',
    'moz:accessibilityChecks' => false,
    'moz:buildID' => '20230414190624',
    'moz:debuggerAddress' => '127.0.0.1:9222',
    'moz:geckodriverVersion' => '0.32.2',
    'moz:headless' => true,
    'moz:platformVersion' => '5.15.0-69-generic',
    'moz:processID' => 647038,
    'moz:profile' => '/tmp/rust_mozprofileB7PKSi',
    'moz:shutdownTimeout' => 60000,
    'moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin' => false,
    'moz:webdriverClick' => true,
    'moz:windowless' => false,
    'pageLoadStrategy' => 'normal',
    'platformName' => 'linux',
    'proxy' => {},
    'setWindowRect' => true,
    'strictFileInteractability' => false,
    'timeouts' => { implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000 },
    'unhandledPromptBehavior' => 'dismiss and notify'
  }
}
```